# Multiple websites, single codebase: git fork?

Tags: git, legacy, legacy-code, git-fork

One of the web applications on which I work is an old legacy system which has recently been migrated to git.  The system is quite large.  Two different websites run off of this same software; however, many parts of the code do site-specific things using simple control statements (if site == 'this' { do custom business logic; }).  This strategy has been used for over a decade, and it's getting ugly.

Because a good portion of the codebase has diverged between the two sites, we're considering forking the repository.  The tricky thing is, most of the code is legitimately shared between the two systems. As such, if a bug is fixed in the shared code, it seems like it would be tricky to get the fix into the fork.  We could use patches, for example.  Or, we could create a branch at the fork point, cherry-pick changes, then use a pull request.  But both of those approaches seem overly complicated to me, and I want to minimize complexity.

Now to the question.  **Does forking seem like a good approach here?  Should we use branches instead, and cherry-pick fixes/enhancements to shared code?**

As an aside, I'll stress again that this is a large legacy system.  We have been working to improve the system, doing things like pulling out shared JavaScript modules into their own repositories and publishing those modules in NPM.  (We're following the guidelines laid out in Michael Feather's book, *Working Effectively with Legacy Code*.) That being said, improving large legacy systems is a slow process.  We want to minimize refactoring, and keep making slow improvements.

Comment: What you're proposing is just another version of the "getting ugly" approach you already have.  It doesn't really fix the problem, it just makes something else ugly.  Instead, I'd suggest some refactoring.  Either extract the shared code from the codebase and have two separate applications which reference the shared code, or extract the different code from the codebase and have a single application which dynamically loads site-specific libraries based on some application configuration.

Comment: Thanks,@David.  I really tend to agree with this, and this has been the tack that we've chose so far (e.g. by moving shared code to npm modules).  But the amount of time it takes to refactor is high, as us the risk of breaking time-tested code.  I was really looking to use a tool (git here) to help with a slow, safe, and carefully planned refactoring effort.  We'd like to leave one system intact and just change the other, but of course propagate any fixes.  But maybe, as you suggest, that's not a good path.  Anyway, thank you for the comment.

Comment: It's a standard business question really.  Technical debt has been amassing over the years, and collectively the team has decided to "deal with it later".  Welcome to later :)  The choice at this point is to incur the cost and correct the problem now, or add more technical debt and "deal with it later" at an even higher cost.  Both are valid approaches, depending on how risks and costs are weighed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know having large amounts of duplicate code is going to be a problem.  Most likely once the sites live in separate repos they would diverge in ways that make swapping patches difficult enough to do correctly that it's not what you'd end up doing - which means you'd end up fixing every bug with two separate development efforts.  I can't imagine the problems associated with the current "branch based on site ID" approach would be worse than that.

I understand the momentum of a large system, but if you were to pick a *systematic* way to separate common code from divergent code - without worrying (yet) about splitting up individual common modules, but just moving toward a 3-repo solution first - you could get there faster than you think.

Comment: Mark: Thanks for the response, but can you clarify a few points?  1) When you say "branch based on site ID" you mean branching in code, right? (As opposed to the VCS.) 2) When you say a 3-repo solution, are you suggesting a repo with common code, then two forks off of that (one per site)?  We are looking for a systematic approach that will hold up over time, and we don't want to exacerbate the current problems or take shortcuts here.  Since we're trying to split parts of the code, we want an approach that is understandable, cost effective, and improves the system slowly over time.

Comment: 1) Yes, I'm referring to logic branches in the code.  I'm saying that as bad as your current situation is, the common-code problems involved in a simple fork are far worse.

Comment: 2) A 3-repo solution would keep common code in one repo, Site 1 code in one repo, and Site 2 code in one repo.  I would not use any forks to get to that solution.

Comment: All right, I appreciate it.  This raises some other project- and language-specific questions about how best to share the code in our situation, but I'll ask those questions separately.  Thanks again.